# iTunes Web Store API search by Genre

Tags: ios, itunes

All,
I'm trying to search the iTunes store for some songs and I can search by artist and song title without a problem. I'm using the following link as a resource:

http://www.apple.com/itunes/affiliates/resources/documentation/itunes-store-web-service-search-api.html

My issue is that I'd like to search by a genre for example Country and songs based on that genre. Does anyone know how to search by genre?

Please let me know.

Thanks!