# How to use iTunes search for genres

Tags: json, webclient, itunes, asp.net-web-api

(I made a major edit as the C# code snippets were not helping but masked the issue - hopefully it is clearer now)

I am trying to get listing of podcasts by genre from iTunes and using the API as described in https://www.apple.com/itunes/affiliates/resources/documentation/itunes-store-web-service-search-api.html the best I can.

I have no difficulties in searcing for a name and parsing / using the response in JSON e.g.the search

```
    https://itunes.apple.com/search?term=Design&media=podcast&entity=podcast&limit=1
```

gives

```
    {
     "resultCount":1,
     "results": [{"wrapperType":"track", "kind":"podcast", "artistId":127446766,"collectionId":73330703, "trackId":73330703, "artistName":"Frances Anderton", "collectionName":"KCRW's DnA: Design & Architecture", "trackName":"KCRW's DnA: Design & Architecture", "collectionCensoredName":"KCRW's DnA: Design & Architecture", "trackCensoredName":"KCRW's DnA: Design & Architecture", "artistViewUrl":"https://itunes.apple.com/us/artist/kcrw/id127446766?mt=2&uo=4", "collectionViewUrl":"https://itunes.apple.com/us/podcast/kcrws-dna-design-architecture/id73330703?mt=2&uo=4", "feedUrl":"http://feeds.kcrw.com/kcrw/de", "trackViewUrl":"https://itunes.apple.com/us/podcast/kcrws-dna-design-architecture/id73330703?mt=2&uo=4", "artworkUrl30":"http://a2.mzstatic.com/us/r30/Podcasts/v4/42/ef/6a/42ef6a04-7873-e82d-716d-ae3f1c6ebca8/mza_1492532737245560899.30x30-50.jpg", "artworkUrl60":"http://a4.mzstatic.com/us/r30/Podcasts/v4/42/ef/6a/42ef6a04-7873-e82d-716d-ae3f1c6ebca8/mza_1492532737245560899.60x60-50.jpg", "artworkUrl100":"http://a2.mzstatic.com/us/r30/Podcasts/v4/42/ef/6a/42ef6a04-7873-e82d-716d-ae3f1c6ebca8/mza_1492532737245560899.100x100-75.jpg", "collectionPrice":0.00, "trackPrice":0.00, "trackRentalPrice":0, "collectionHdPrice":0, "trackHdPrice":0, "trackHdRentalPrice":0, "releaseDate":"2014-12-30T08:00:00Z", "collectionExplicitness":"notExplicit", "trackExplicitness":"notExplicit", "trackCount":25, "country":"USA", "currency":"USD", "primaryGenreName":"Design", "radioStationUrl":"https://itunes.apple.com/station/idra.73330703", "artworkUrl600":"http://a3.mzstatic.com/us/r30/Podcasts/v4/42/ef/6a/42ef6a04-7873-e82d-716d-ae3f1c6ebca8/mza_1492532737245560899.600x600-75.jpg", "genreIds":["1402", "26", "1301"], "genres":["Design", "Podcasts", "Arts"]}]
    }
```

But when trying to get a list of podcasts based on genre, e.g. when using genre id "1402" for trying to get list from the genre "Design" (happens with whatever id number I use, actually) using the following

```
    https://itunes.apple.com/search?term=1402&media=podcast&entity=podcast&attribute=genreIndex&limit=1
```

I get is this

```
{
 "resultCount":0,
 "results": []
}
```

(I am taking the ids from here http://www.apple.com/itunes/affiliates/resources/documentation/genre-mapping.html)

Obviously I am doing something trivial wrong here.. :(.. Is there something missing from the API description?

Comment: What is _"not able to get anything"_? What _does_ happen?

Comment: Sorry for dumb "not getting anything" - yes, I get something, a string `{"resultCount":0, "results":[]}`

Comment: Are there supposed to be any results? What if you perform the same search in the app?

Comment: Yes, in my Windows 8.1 machine iTunes can filter podcasts by genre

Comment: And the listing in iTunes for "Design" I am using here as example is actually quite long.. Dozens and dozens.. It is a subgenre under "Arts"

Comment: Looks like @user1048676 http://stackoverflow.com/users/1048676/user1048676 had quite similar issue quite some time agio -- but did not get any answers http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11355603/itunes-web-store-api-search-by-genre?rq=1 :(

Comment: Okay - this is looking like a dead end based on a thread http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13833521/search-apple-app-store-by-genre-with-ios-obj-c/13877257#13877257 and aswers by Fábio Oliveira (http://stackoverflow.com/users/1130894/f%C3%A1bio-oliveira).   In another thread http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13918580/use-the-apple-search-api-to-search-by-genre there was a "hack" but it seems to not work for podcasts, perhaps for software only.. Sigh

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Why not use genreId like so? It's an undocumented search parameter that I stumbled on by accident.

```
https://itunes.apple.com/search?term=podcast&genreId=1402&limit=200
```

Comment: Out of all different combinations on that API I tried before implementing "my own" solution I failed to try "podcast" as term.. ;).. Yes, your answer fits my question, thanks!

Comment: Glad I could help. I was struggling with the same situation for the longest time because the rss feed doesn't include the feedUrl for podcasts.

Answer (score 2):

Okay - looks like the strategy was wrong and using that API does not work for getting list of podcasts of a desired genre.

The way forward is to use different API, e.g.

```
    https://itunes.apple.com/us/rss/topaudiopodcasts/genre=1406/json
```

to get a list of podcasts. You do not get feed address directly from here but you get feed id and can use that to lookup rest of whatever you need via the search API.