# itunes Seach API: Get results only from specific country

Tags: json, api, itunes, itunes-search-api

I am trying to search through the itunes Search API for genres in a specific country.

I already went through [How to use iTunes search for genres](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27760167/how-to-use-itunes-search-for-genres) and is working that I recieve the Podcasts from the defined genre.

Now I would like to receive just results from "Germany". But unfortunately I always get podcasts from around the world. 
Here is my url: https://itunes.apple.com/de/search?term=podcast&genreId=1549&limit=200&country=de

Does any one has an idea how to filter these results.

Thank you.